# What is the bare minimum to mine?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, linux

What are pools used for and what Linux x86 program could I use to mine Monero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the bare minimum to mine?

Pretty much any computing device can mine.

> What are pools used for

To pool the resources of multiple miners to increase the chance of finding blocks.

> and what Linux x86 program could I use to mine Monero?

XMRig for pool or solo mining, the official wallet/daemon for solo.